# Combine several math symbols in one symbol properly

Tags: mathtools, stacking-symbols

How to put **several math symbols together in one** and make it work as a single math symbol? It should be **invulnerable to font size and scaling**.

For example I want to have this weird symbol:

[image: i want this]

and I defined it as: `\newcommand{\upDisCov}{\ensuremath{\uparrow\kern-3.5pt\scalebox{.86}{$|$}\kern-8.2pt\raisebox{-2pt}{$\smallsmile$}}}`. 
(I know I shouldn't have used `\kern`).

The symbol is messed in subscript or when the font size is changed (from 12 to 10).
I can use \mbox for maintain its form in a superscript but it does not scale.

[image]

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\upDisCov}{\ensuremath{\uparrow\kern-.5em\scalebox{.86}{$|$}\kern-.2em\raisebox{-.2em}{$\smallsmile$}}}
\begin{document}
\upDisCov
$A^{\upDisCov}$
$A^{\mbox{\upDisCov}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: ops I forgot MWE, I will add it in seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\upDisCov}{%
  \mathord{\vphantom{\uparrow}\text{%
    \ooalign{%
      $\uparrow$\kern-0.05em\raisebox{0.07ex}{\scalebox{0.88}{$|$}}\cr
      \kern0.02em\raisebox{-0.2em}{$\smallsmile$}\cr
    }%
  }}%
}
\begin{document}

$\upDisCov$
$A^{\upDisCov}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i think you'll find that, at 10pt, the vertical is too tall.  i found that using instead a `\vrule  height1.6ex depth.4ex width.04em` negotiates that size change nicely.  since it doesn't have the sidebearings of the `$|$`, the kerning needs to be adjusted.  and why didn't you use `\mkern ...mu`?  (that also migrates nicely to `\large` and `\Large`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I see no difference in height at 10pt. The rule has the disadvantage of having sharp ends.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\newcommand\foo{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0pt}{%
  \stackengine{-.85\LMex}{\SavedStyle\uparrow}{\SavedStyle\scaleto{\smile}{0.75\LMex}}{U}{l}%
  {F}{F}{S}}{\SavedStyle\stretchrel*{\vert}{\uparrow}\kern0.25\LMex}{O}{r}{F}{F}{L}}}}}
\begin{document}
$A\foo B\quad A^{\foo}$\par
$\scriptstyle A\foo B$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle A\foo B$
\end{document}
```

At 10pt:

[image]

...and at 12pt

[image]